# Forgot to add salt to french fries while soaking it in hot water

Tags: salt, potatoes, french-fries

I tried to make french fries at home for the first time. As I searched over the internet, there are four steps,

1. Soak the potatoes in cold water for 20 mins
2. Soak the potatoes now in hot water for 10 mins with salt in it(I forgot to add salt in water)
3. Fry the potatoes in sim mode for 10 mins ( I did that already)
4. Fry the potatoes now in a high manner until they get brown (I need to do hereafter)

After the third step, I realised I had not added salt while soaking the potatoes. Is there any way could I add salt now before/while fry it?

Comment: I've made french fries a couple times successfully, and I've never salted them before frying.

Comment: @TomSmilack I think then the one I saw/trying should be an Indian style. Without salt, we do/eat nothing. :')

Comment: Also, without salt, it tastes like raw, boiled potatoes.

Comment: I'm saying salting before frying is unnecessary - you can toss the fries in salt and spices afterward, as in Stephie's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any salt added during the soaking step won’t make your fries significantly salty, during blancing the potatoes will precook and absorb some water and if salted, some salt (a 3% brine is suggested [here](http://www.cookingissues.com/index.html%3Fp=4043.html)). But the average French fry recipes I am familiar with typically don’t salt the water and many don’t parboil. - I never salted any soaking water and still got good results.

Fries are usually salted (or spiced, if you prefer) *right after* the last frying step when the remaining frying oil helps the salt stick to the fries.

In short: Yes, there are sources that insist on salted blanching water, and maybe it’s the way to perfection, but if you didn’t, simply salt afterwards.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I poured the salt on fries then had it with tomato sauce. It was much better than I thought.